# Syntax error regexp в условии

Tags: регулярные-выражения, bash, shell

Имеется некоторый file.xml вида

```
<data_set type="1"> 
  <data_model type="2"> 
  </data_model>
  <data_model type="3">
    <data_model type="3"> 
    </data_model>
  </data_model>
</data_set>
```

И есть скрипт на баше regexp.sh

```
main_file="./file.xml"

while read str
do
    if [[ "$str" =~ <data_[a-z]{3}+>$ ]]
    then 
        echo "$str" >> $debugt
    else
        echo "$str" >> $debugf
    fi
done < "$main_file"
```

Однако при выполнении вылазит ошибка

```
./regexp.sh: line 12: syntax error at line 19: `~(E)<data_[a-z]{3}+>$ ]]
        then
                echo "$str" >> $debugt
        else
                echo "$str" >> $debugf
        fi
done < "$main_file"./regexp.sh: line 12: syntax error at line 19: `' unexpected
```

не совсем понятно в чем проблема. и как ее можно исправить. 
Возможно имхо проблема связана с фигурными скобками

Comment: не знаю, что именно вы хотите найти вашим регулярным выражением, но оно не соответствует ни одной из строк из образцового файла. вероятно, вам следует задать новый вопрос, в котором стоит изложить — что же именно вы хотите найти, и как должно выглядеть рег. выражение.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, ну, скажем так: необходимо отобрать все теги подходящие под следующий шаблон: `<data_*3 буквы**пробел**какие угодно символы кроме >*>`

Comment: лучше задайте новый вопрос.

Comment: не надо извращаться http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333755/extract-xml-value-in-bash-script баш тут не нужен

Comment: @I.Smirnov, если Вам дан исчерпывающий ответ - отметьте его, нажав галочку рядом с ним.

Answer (score 2):

в строке с регулярным выражением здесь:

```
if [[ "$str" =~ <data_[a-z]{3}+>$ ]]
```

спецсимволы надо предварять обратным слэшем <kbd>\</kbd>:

```
if [[ "$str" =~ \<data_[a-z]{3}+\>$ ]]
```

либо можно заключить всё регулярное выражение в скобки:

```
if [[ "$str" =~ (<data_[a-z]{3}+>$) ]]
```

Comment: пробовал такой вариант, но не помогло

Comment: если скобки фигурные убираю вообще, то все работает (ошибок нет), но на выход дается не совсем то, что необходимо получить

Comment: @I.Smirnov, прошу прощения, ввёл вас в заблуждение: заключение регулярного выражения в кавычки «отменяет» его действие. должно быть без кавычек, но спецсимволы (типа знаков больше/меньше, пробела и т.п.) должны предваряться обратным слэшем.

Comment: ошибки нет, но на на выход дается не совсем то, что необходимо получить. п.с. кстати, необходимости экранировки символов больше меньше в выражениях `if [[ "$str" =~ <data_[a-z]{3}+>$ ]]`  нет

Comment: Не спец в баше, но всегда думал что в этом случае выражение должно браться в скобки `(<data_[a-z]{3}+>$)`

Comment: @I.Smirnov, *на на выход дается не совсем то, что необходимо получить* — регулярное выражение у вас, действительно, «странное». но это совершенно другой вопрос. // ошибка есть, если не экранировать спецсимволы. возможно, вы используете не bash для интерпретации вашего файла regexp.sh. или bash какой-нибудь экзотической сборки.

Comment: @Romario, не обязательно, но возможно. кстати, спасибо за напоминание, в скобках экранирование не требуется, сейчас добавлю в ответ.