# Написание regexp для ksh

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Необходимо написать регулярку, которая в xml-нике ищет тэги вида

```
<data_*3 буквы**пробел**какие угодно символы кроме >*>
```

[UPD] Интерпретатор не bash, как было указано ранеее, а ksh

Comment: В чем проблема? Какие варианты вы уже пробовали написать самостоятельно?

Comment: воспользуйтесь https://regex101.com/, очень удобный инструмент

Comment: @newman писал регулярку для использования в условии на bash `if [[ $str =~ <data_[a-z]{3}\s[^>]+>) ]]` однако на такую запись интерпретатор ругался. [сабж](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/508425/syntax-error-regexp-%D0%B2-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B8?noredirect=1#comment614210_508425) . Заключение в кавычки в необходимому результату не привело

Comment: А зачем вы это делаете if на баше. Может стоит использовать sed или grep. Или вообще perl. тут в интернете много чего интересного про прямые регулярки в bash пишут, что там например \s может не работать и ее надо заменять на `[[:space:]]`. И вообще информацию о том, что требуется регулярка именно для bash надо указывать прямо в вопросе, потому как у него свой диалект

Comment: @Mike, ну, наверно вы правы, с `sed` будет проще это сделать, но просто ранее возник вопрос чтобы реализовать регулярку, которая использовалась  именно в `if`. А именно тут как мне кажется проблема возникает с использованием `{ }`, а попытка экранировать скобки не особо помогает

Comment: Уточните,  текст `<data_...` начинается в любом месте строки и после него до конца строки не должно быть символа `>` ?

Answer (score 1):

На моей версии bash отработала такая регулярка:

```
if [[ $str =~ \<data_[a-z]{3}[[:space:]][^\>]*\> ]]
```

UPD: проверил на ksh 93, так же работает

Comment: imho это выражение работает  только если после `[:space:]` как раз есть любое количество `>`

Comment: @avp Там стоит `^` т.е. отрицание. И если заменить * на + и поставить за пробелом в тестовой строке `>` то проверка не проходит, а если любой другой символ - проходит. так что все точно работает

Comment: Вы написали `[^\>]*\>` , что означает -- `все что угодно, кроме > сколько угодно раз (в т.ч. ни разу), а после этого >` -- можете просто проверить в терминале. На самом деле в вопрос-то другой -- *до конца строки* **не должно быть** *>*. Вот, как в bash обозначить конец строки я и не знаю. (на практике все это легко решается использованием grep)

Comment: @avp, смотрите предыдущий вопрос того же пользователя.

Comment: @avp не вижу в вопросе и комментариях к нему ни слова про конец строки. С учетом что это xml там может быть несколько тегов слитно без всяких концов строк.

Comment: Тогда весь этот конец `[^\>]*\>` просто не имеет смысла. Ваша регулярка сопоставится, например с `'<data_abc >fkj>fk'` (т.е. неважно, что там за пробелом. Да, там **должен быть >**, а после него что угодно. Не вижу смысла в таких выражениях (видимо ТС просто ошибся и не смог сформулировать, что ему на самом деле надо (весьма типично, поэтому вообще о регулярках простым программистам лучше не знать))

Comment: @avp Я же видя такой вопрос решаю, что ТС его максимально упростил, а позже расставит например круглые скобки для захвата неких подстрок из середины данного выражения. тем более, что он дословно расписал какие символы где проверять. И судя по комментариям он понимает регулярки, но конкретно bash диалект вызвал проблемы (из за угловых скобок)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, да, глянул его предыдущий вопрос. Думаю, (если упрощенно) ему нужны все строки, в которых встречается `<data_... >`. Т.е. регулярка в этом ответе подойдет (а ее часть `[^\>]*` можно заменить для простоты восприятия на `.*`)

Comment: @Mike, а что, подвыражения в круглых скобках в bash-e тоже работают? (я просто не знаю)

Comment: @avp, согласно `man bash`, правая часть оператора `=~` *considered an extended regular expression and matched accordingly (as in regex(3))*

Comment: @avp Работают, захваты собираются в массив BASH_REMATCH

Comment: Спасибо, коллеги. Кто бы собрал краткий справочник полезных bash советов с примерами (ну, не вчитываться же каждый раз в этот man -)). Может тут такую тему открыть?

Answer (score 0):

`<`, `data`, 3 буквы, пробел, все что угодно кроме `>`, то есть ищем до ближайшего `>`, используя ленивый квантификатор `*?`.

```
<data_[a-zA-z]{3} .*?>
```

https://regex101.com/r/mY6bX0/1

Comment: А с каких пор в bash PCRE регулярки?

Comment: @avp изначально просто забыл упомянуть, что регулярка для баша

Comment: `grep -P` в чем проблема использовать?